# Python, split function on character 0x9d

Tags: python, python-3.x

0x9d is used to seperate files that have been stored as a single file. But 0x9d is not a valid character in Pythons UTF-8.

This means I can't even read the file without opening it in binary.

Does anyone know the easiest way I could split the file into its constituent files.

Comment: So read it as binary. After you split it, you can use `.decode()` to parse the component files as UTF-8.

Comment: Why not use a standard format like tar or zip to combine multiple files?

Comment: If `0x9d` is in the file, load it as a binary string, and use `b'\x9d'` as a separator. `.decode` can also handle byte strings

Comment: Using the Latin-1 encoding allows all non recognised characters to be referenced using their hex code.